# Delay table view loading or load array before viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm using a webservice to fill an array of items, which then are used to fill cells of my table view.

Now i'm having an issue with the table view itself. When I check the " numberofrows" method, the array isn't loaded yet. For some reason it loads "right after" that (according to my nslogs & breakpoints), even though i've put every loading method as early as i could in that controller.

Now what i don't know is :

- is there a way to delay the table view creation so i'm sure my array is loaded?
- is there a way to load my array earlier? It's currently my first line in the viewDidLoad. (calling another class, which then calls the webservice and returns an array, but by then, the table view is already loaded and empty).

What i've tried : Putting a tableview reloadData. But it simply doesn't work. For some reason the compiler reads the line but doesn't load anything new, even though at that point the array is full.

Am i missing something?

(My tableview works just fine if I put hardcoded objects in my array)

I can edit and add some code that you guys would request, but since this looks like a school problem here, maybe i just forgot something.

Guys, i'm all ears !
Edit :

My different methods ; i've removed unecessary code for clearer reading.
The compiler NEVER goes in the cellForRow because numberOfRows is returning a zero number.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCellTableViewCell";
    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [self.tbUpcomingEvents dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.lbTitle = [_eventList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

number of rows ; the nslog returns zero.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numOfRows : %i", [_eventList count]);
    return [_eventList count];
}
```

my webservice method, this is the method calle from the "webservice class" to load the data.
Here, the NSLog shows a full array.

```
- (void)loadData:(NSMutableArray*)arrayEvent
{
//arrayEvent is full from the internet data. eventList is also full on the NSLog.
    _eventList = arrayEvent;
    NSLog(@"LoadData : %i", [_eventList count]);
    [self.tbUpcomingEvents reloadData];
}
```

my viewdidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Calling my UseCaseController to load the data from the internet.
    UCC *sharedUCC = [UCC sharedUCC];
    [sharedUCC getUserEventsInDbDis:self :_user];

}
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls reload tableview, numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections, and cellForRow methods as well

Comment: I've edited according to your requests ! numberOfSections is just the default 1 though, so i have no method for that.

Comment: breakpoint in load data and numberOfRows. Does numberOfRows get called after loadData? Log out`self.tbUpcomingEvent` in load data to make sure its not nil. Log out `self.tbUpcomingEvents.delegate` to make sure it is also set.

Comment: numberOfRows is called first, indeed. Well that zooms on the issue i guess. And in my loaddata the tableview AND the delegate are logging (null). I don't know why though, everything is connected and the tableview works if i send it hardcoded data.

Comment: Does it log out as null in View Did load?

Comment: NSLogging my tableview shows this when i put it on the top of viewDidLoad: ( short answer : no, its not null !)


2014-07-05 19:55:08.135 ApiSport[797:60b]  vdl tb : <UITableView: 0xd189e00; frame = (0 94; 320 338); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbe328e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbe31490>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: How is the tableview loaded/created? Is the controller loaded from a nib or progamatically? How is the tableview added to the view?

Comment: I storyboarded it, linked it to my controllers delegate & protocol, then linked it in my .h to create an outlet (tbUpcomingEvents), and added the 2 protocols. 
That's all i did + the code you saw earlier. 

So i guess the answer to your question is : loaded from nib

Comment: Is this a view controller or tableview controller?

Comment: a View controller and i added a tableview in it afterwards.

Comment: I would guess that the outlet for tbUpcomingEvents is not really connected because if the array is hardcoded the Delegate and data source will get called if connected. Try to log out tbUpcomingEvents before and after `[super viewDidLoad]` to see if the super overrides it.

Comment: Pre & post super viewdidload shows the same result on NSlog. the same as i showed you earlier. :(

Comment: Might need to post the code/project on git for further digging

Comment: Sorry, i can't do that :\ I've tried loading the data a previous controller (and then just send the array of objects through segue), but even that doesn't work. For some reason, when i start laoding the data, the compiler skips everthing, goes in prepareForSegue, goes to next view, then comes back and load the data, and the problem stays the same.
This makes absolutly no sense.

Comment: As a note: the compiler has nothing to do with runtime. Using the term when talking about how the app runs will probably confuse others when you ask future iOS questions

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using webservices. So it is executing your code in the block which means it is running in separate thread. Now as per apple documentation UI updates should happen in main thread. So for table creation you need to include the same in below GCD code:-

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,()^{

    // write your code for table creation here
  });
```

Comment: Though this answer may be correct, don't just spit out answers until you know that it is an answer. Many other things could be wrong. We should not make random guesses as to the solution but take the time make sure we understand the problem.

Comment: I've never used such code, but your line seems pretty straightforward. I just need to understand this to try it out :  What is the GCD code ?

Comment: Grand Central Dispatch is I believe a wrapper for NSThread. it is used for thread operations. Most API Calls are done on background threads. This method above will make sure the operations in the block are run on the main thread. Many UI operations have to be done on the main thread.